# how theme.spacing() is functioning?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, materialize

As per the document in material-ui,it is providing space between the components.  But I could get the way it is getting height and width here:

```
width: theme.spacing(20),
height: theme.spacing(15)
```

How is `theme.spacing()` setting the width and height here?

Answer (score 17):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  spacing: 8,
});
```

When your theme is define, you have a spacing value. By default this value is `8px`. So when you call `theme.spacing(20)`, if the `spacing value` is `8` it return simply `20 * 8` => `160px`.

Source : https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/

Comment: By default, the value is `8`, not `8px`. `theme.spacing(20)` returns the number `160` as opposed to the string `160px`. So, how are we intended to apply those number values to components?

Comment: @stone Material UI converts numbers into pixel values, e.g. `8` will become `8px`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify which distance you are spacing, resort of the default CSS use of 1, 2, 3, or 4 parameters:

> (top: SpacingArgument, right: SpacingArgument, bottom:
> SpacingArgument, left: SpacingArgument)
> (T, R, B, L)

Below is how I got mine to with in a React project.

ThemeContext.js

```
    import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
    export const ThemeContext = createContext()
    ...
    function ThemeContextProvider(props) {
            const theme = createTheme({
            spacing: [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64],
        });
    ...
    return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>
                {props.children}
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        )
    }

    export default ThemeContextProvider
```

Contact.js

```
function Contacts() {
const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
...
<Container maxWidth="sm">
<Box sx={{
    bgcolor: 'none',
    border: '2px solid #4faeba',
    height: 'fitContent',
    borderRadius: '20px',
    m: theme.spacing(16),
}}
>
```

Hope that helps. Hit me up if this doesn't work and I'll work with ya to make it work on your end .

Resource: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/spacing/#multiple-arity